# How to get a sender's email address?

Tags: vba, email, outlook

I want Outlook to perform an action on email from a certain email address.

In the ThisOutlookSession I have:

```
Private Sub Application_NewMail() 'This triggers when a new email is recieved
    Call TestSub
End Sub
```

In a module I have:

```
Public Sub TestSub()
    Dim Msg                 As Outlook.MailItem
    Dim FromEmailAddress    As String

    FromEmailAddress = Msg.SenderEmailAddress

    If FromEmailAddress = "Test@example.com" Then
        MsgBox ("Hello")
    End If

End Sub
```

I get

> Run-time error '91':
>   Object variable or With block variable not set

on `FromEmailAddress = Msg.SenderEmailAddress`.

I have tried many variations on my code and exhausted the powers of Google.

Comment: You haven't set Msg to anything.

Comment: Maybe try this instead:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/Outlook.Items.ItemAdd

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following code:

```
Dim oInbox    As Outlook.Folder
Dim oItem     As Object
Dim Msg       As MailItem

Set oInbox = ActiveExplorer.Session.DefaultStore.GetRootFolder().Folders("Inbox")
For Each oItem In oInbox.Items
    If TypeOf oItem Is MailItem Then
        Set Msg = oItem
        FromEmailAddress = Msg.SenderEmailAddress
    Else
        Debug.Print "Skipping " & TypeName(oItem)
    End If
Next
```

Answer (score 4):

*Its also good to check if the Sender is **`SMTP`** or **`GetExchangeUser`***

```
        Dim Email_Address As String

        If Item.SenderEmailType = "SMTP" Then
            Email_Address = Item.SenderEmailAddress
        Else
            If Item.SenderEmailType = "EX" Then
                Email_Address = Item.Sender.GetExchangeUser.PrimarySmtpAddress
            End If
        End If
```