# Getting recipient's email address in right format, not /O=EXCHANGE…

Tags: vba, outlook

I'm trying to check outgoing email addresses and to do so I use the following code:

```
Dim objMail As Outlook.MailItem
Set objMail = Item

Dim objRecipients As Outlook.Recipients
Set objRecipients = objMail.Recipients
```

and use it like this:

```
Set objRecipients = objMail.Recipients

For i = objRecipients.Count To 1 Step -1
    vntRecipients.Add objRecipients.Item(i).Address
    Debug.Print "Recipient"
    Debug.Print objRecipients.Item(i).Address
Next
```

Afterwards I have all addresses in vntRecipients. When I look at the log file I see, that it's not always an email address but very often (all internal email addresses, but also external email addresses) something like this:

```
/O=EXCHANGELABS/OU=EXCHANGE ADMINISTRATIVE GROUP (FYDXYXYXYXYXYXYXY)/CN=RECIPIENTS/CN=BYXXYXYXYXYXYXYXYXYXYXYXYXYX0B-S.BLALBA
```

There are different formats, but I guess it's due to the O365 Exchange server.

Is there any way to get the email address to compare the domain to my trusted domain list?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60460848/4539709

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested but the docs probably suggest using the following:

```vb
Dim pa As Outlook.PropertyAccessor
Const PR_SMTP_ADDRESS As String = "https://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x39FE001E" 

Set pa = objRecipients.Item(i).PropertyAccessor 
Debug.Print objRecipients.Item(i).name & " SMTP=" & pa.GetProperty(PR_SMTP_ADDRESS)
```

Source: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/outlook/concepts/address-book/obtain-the-e-mail-address-of-a-recipient

Comment: Thanks, but i understood that this is not working anymore because the schema is noch available at https://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x39FE001E

When access the url i just get an error

Comment: @dehein2 you will need to check `SenderEmailType` then get the email address

Comment: see example here https://stackoverflow.com/a/60460848/4539709