# For loop only shows the first object

Tags: python, for-loop, outlook

I have a code that loops through a list of mails, but it is only showing the first result, even though there are also other matches.

The other results require me to loop over the mails again only to return the value.

```py
mail = win32com.client.Dispatch('outlook.application').GetNamespace("MAPI")
inbox = mail.GetDefaultFolder(6).Folders["Trial"]
df = pd.read_excel(r"C://User//Asus//Test//Test.xlsx", sheet_name = 'Sheet1')
mail = df.iloc[:,0].tolist() #this is the list of emails i.e. ends with gmail.com
processed = mail.GetDefaultFolder(6).Folders["Trial"].Folders["Done"]
msg = inbox.Items.GetFirst()
add = msg.SenderEmailAddress

for attch in msg.Attachments:
    if any([add.endswith(m) for m in mail]) and attch.FileName[-3:] != 'png':
        fname = attch.FileName
        dir = "C://User//Asus//Output//"
        tempdir = os.path.join(dir, fname)
        attch.SaveAsFile(tempdir)
msg.Move(processed) #move the emails that completed processed to another folder
```

**Updated Codes V1**

I had revised the codes according to the suggestion, but with bad luck, now it only loops through the first two email..

```
mail = win32com.client.Dispatch('outlook.application').GetNamespace("MAPI")
inbox = mail.GetDefaultFolder(6).Folders["Trial"]
df = pd.read_excel(r"C://User//Asus//Test//Test.xlsx", sheet_name = 'Sheet1')
mail = df.iloc[:,0].tolist() #this is the list of emails i.e. ends with gmail.com
processed = mail.GetDefaultFolder(6).Folders["Trial"].Folders["Done"]
add = msg.SenderEmailAddress

for msg in inbox.Items:
    print(msg.Subject)
    for attch in msg.Attachments:
        if any([add.endswith(m) for m in mail]) and attch.FileName[-3:] != 'png':
           fname = attch.FileName
           dir = "C://User//Asus//Output//"
           tempdir = os.path.join(dir, fname)
           attch.SaveAsFile(tempdir)
           msg.Move(processed) #move the emails that completed processed to another folder
```

**Updated Codes V2**

```
for msg in inbox.Items:
    try:
       for attch in msg.Attachments:
           if msg.SenderEmailType == "SMTP" and attch.FileName[-3:] != 'png':
               add = msg.SenderEmailAddress
               print(add, "address")
               fname = attch.FileName
               dir = "C://User//Asus//Output//"
               tempdir = os.path.join(dir, fname)
               attch.SaveAsFile(tempdir)
               msg.Move(processed)
           elif msg.SenderEmailType == "EX" and attch.FileName[-3:] != 'png':
               add = msg.Sender.GetExchangeUser().PrimarySmtpAddress
               print(add, "address")
               fname = attch.FileName
               dir = "C://User//Asus//Output//"
               tempdir = os.path.join(dir, fname)
               attch.SaveAsFile(tempdir)
               msg.Move(processed)
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        continue
```

Comment: The loop processes the attachments of the first mail. You need an additional loop to iterate through the mails.

Comment: You only take the first mail with "msg = inbox.Items.GetFirst()". You should have another loop like: "for msg in inbox.Items:" to correctly iterate over all the messages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Remove `msg = inbox.Items.GetFirst()` and try*

*Example*

```
for msg in inbox.Items:
    print(msg.Subject)
    for attch in msg.Attachments:
        if any(.....
```

---

Could be `SenderEmailAddress` so check `SenderEmailType` `smtp` or `Exchange`

*[MailItem.SenderEmailType property (Outlook)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.mailitem.senderemailtype)*

> <sub>Returns a String that represents the type of entry for the email address of the sender of the Outlook item, such as 'SMTP' for Internet address, 'EX' for a Microsoft Exchange server address, etc. Read-only.</sub>

---

*Example*

```
import win32com.client

mail = win32com.client.Dispatch('outlook.application').GetNamespace("MAPI")
inbox = mail.GetDefaultFolder(6)

for msg in inbox.Items:
    try:
        if msg.SenderEmailType == "SMTP":
            add = msg.SenderEmailAddress
            print(add, "address")
            # for attch in msg.Attachments:
            #     if any(.....

        elif msg.SenderEmailType == "EX":
            add = msg.Sender.GetExchangeUser().PrimarySmtpAddress
            print(add, "address")
            # for attch in msg.Attachments:
            #     if any(.....
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        continue
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/60460848/4539709

Comment: hi @0m3r, I've tried with the given solutions, the first for loops able to show all the subjects of the emails. But the second for loop of the attachments part only success for the first email..

Comment: hi @0m3r, to update that after double check the codes are running now according to your suggestion. But the problem is it was successfully looping thru all the emails at thee first run, and then I rerun it again, it only loops thru the first two email..

Comment: did you indent `msg.Move(processed)` same as `attch.SaveAsFile(tempdir)`? @mayliew, was the emails moved? if you are still  having the same issue, update your questions with new code but don't delete the original code, just add the new code so i can take look at it

Comment: hi @0m3r, sorry for the late response. I have updated the code according without deleting the original code as above. I had tried indent the msg.Move, the emails was moving but it only moves the first two emails. I have also tried to align the indent to for attch line but still only loop two emails

Comment: hi @0m3r, i have tried with your codes and combined with the save attachment steps. Now it successfully loop through all the emails and saving all the attachment. However, the emails that have been looped doesn't move to the "processed" folder. May I know could it be my indentation for ```msg.Moved(processed``` incorrect? I have tried several times on diff indents, but the output shows ```<unknown>.Moved```

Comment: @mayliew, cod looks okay- can you check if the `msg` has `png` file? `!=` mean NOT EQUAL operator

Comment: hi @0m3r, yes the msg do have png file, I put this ```!=``` condition because I want python to ignore the png file and just download other files in the emails. Should I change ```and``` to ```or``` instead?

Comment: @mayliew  first check `SenderEmailType ` then do `for attch in msg.Attachments:` next check `if attch.FileName[-3:] != 'png':` try that also see this example if it helps  https://stackoverflow.com/a/74856469/4539709

Comment: hi @0m3r, sorry for the late update. I have give it a try on changing the sequence, and it works well and loop through all the emails. Found a fact that if I remove the line msg.Move it will able to loop through all the emails. But if I include msg.Move in the command, it will only loop through the first two emails..