# Appending Outlook multiple attachment file names into a list in Python

Tags: python, list, outlook, append, attachment

I'm currently working on a script that reads unread emails in a folder and appends the file names of the attachments into a list for further data manipulation.

The script works if there is only one attachment per email, but I am having trouble getting it to recognize when there are multiple attachments in an email (2+).

Here is the code I am working with so far:

```
outlook = win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application")
mapi = outlook.GetNamespace("MAPI")

inbox = mapi.Folders['user@outlook.com'].Folders['Inbox'].Folders['Folder1']
 
message = inbox.Items

contents = [] attachment_name = []

for mail in message:
    if mail.UnRead == True and mail.Attachments.Count > 0: # Grab all emails that are unread AND have an attachment
        attachments = mail.Attachments 
        m_attach = len([i for i in attachments])
        contents.append(mail.body)
        contents.append(mail.Subject)
        for i in range(1, m_attach):
            attachment = attachments.Item(i)
            attachment_name.append(attachment.FileName)

print(attachment_name)
```

Answer (score 1):

*Remove the `for i in range(1, m_attach):` and use*

```
    contents.append(mail.body)
    contents.append(mail.Subject)
    for attachment in attachments:
        print(attachment.FileName)
        attachment_name.append(attachment.FileName)
```

**Edit see comment**

*For specific file type, try*

```
    for attachment in attachments:
        if str(attachment.FileName).endswith(".pdf"):
            print(attachment.FileName)
```

*Or use list for multiple file types*

```
    extensions = ['pdf', 'gif']
    for attachment in attachments:
        for ext in extensions:
            if str(attachment.FileName).endswith(ext):
                print(attachment.FileName)
```

Comment: This worked, but it is picking up the embedded photos in signature bodies now. Ultimately I want to be able to read in and download both PDF attachments and embedded images in the email body, but exclude the embedded images in signature bodies. Is there a way to do so?

Comment: Hmm, so there's no way to distinguish between embedded images in the body vs. in the signature block? Sometimes I'll get emails with embedded images that are the same file type as the signature block images (e.g. image001.png), which indicates that there's no way to parse out the embedded image via the name or file type.

Comment: @selereth it depends how the signature is setup, if you look at the `html` source code, for embedded `<img src=”cid:imageid”>`  or for Hosted images in the signature `<img height=”150″ width=”150″ src=”https://stackoverflow.com/img.png”>`  so play with it :-)