# Python to Forward specific mails with attachments recieved today in outlook

Tags: python, outlook, email-attachments, win32com, office-automation

I'm trying to figure out a way to forward emails with attachments received today

from " invoice@email.com" to "Remas@email.com".

I am stuck in that line, What to put here exactly to let it know that any attachment received from  invoice@email.com" today, send it to "Remas@email.com" automatically.

What to type here ?

```
messages = inbox.Items(????????)
```

My code:

```
import win32com.client
import time
import datetime as dt
from os import path



outlook = win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application").GetNamespace("MAPI")
inbox = outlook.GetDefaultFolder(6)
messages = inbox.Items

for message in messages:
    NewMsg = message.Forward()
    NewMsg.Body = message.Body
    NewMsg.Subject = message.Subject
    NewMsg.To = "Remas@email.com"
    #NewMsg.Send()
```

Comment: Why are you trying to do this in Python, instead of using Outlook's built-in forwarding capability?

Answer (score 0):

Work with [Items.Restrict method (Outlook)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/Outlook.Items.Restrict) to apply a filter to the inbox.Items collection

Example

```
import win32com.client
import time
import datetime as dt
from os import path

outlook = win32com.client.Dispatch(
    "Outlook.Application").GetNamespace("MAPI")

inbox = outlook.GetDefaultFolder(6)
messages = inbox.Items

today = str(dt.date.today())

filter_message = f"([ReceivedTime] > '{today} 00:00 AM') AND " \
                 f"([SenderEmailAddress] = 'invoice@email.com')"

for message in messages.Restrict(filter_message):
    # if message has attachments
    if message.Attachments.Count > 0:
        NewMsg = message.Forward()
        NewMsg.HTMLBody = message.HTMLBody
        NewMsg.Subject = message.Subject
        NewMsg.To = "Remas@email.com"
        # NewMsg.Send()
        NewMsg.Display()
```

You may also wanna check [MailItem.SenderEmailType property (Outlook)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.mailitem.senderemailtype)

> <sub>Returns a String that represents the type of entry for the email address of the sender of the Outlook item, such as 'SMTP' for Internet address, 'EX' for a Microsoft Exchange server address, etc. Read-only.</sub>

Example

https://stackoverflow.com/a/74816451/4539709

Answer (score 0):

Instead of iterating over all items in the Outlook folder:

```
for message in messages:
    NewMsg = message.Forward()
```

You need to use the `Find`/`FindNext` or `Restrict` methods of the `Items` class. They allow getting items that correspond to your conditions and iterate over them only. You may get items recieved today by using the following search criteria:

```
strFilter = "%today("urn:schemas:httpmail:datereceived")%"
```

To get items for a specific time frame (for example, several days or hours) you may combine conditions using logical operators:

```
'This filter uses urn:schemas:httpmail namespace 
    strFilter = ""urn:schemas:httpmail:datereceived"" > '{datStartUTC}' AND ""urn:schemas:httpmail:datereceived"" < '{datEndUTC}'"
```

Read more about filtering items using a date-time comparisons in the [Filtering Items Using a Date-time Comparison](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/outlook/how-to/search-and-filter/filtering-items-using-a-date-time-comparison) article.

Also you may get items that has any files attached, so you don't need to iterate over all items found for a specific date range:

```
" "urn:schemas:httpmail:hasattachment"=1 "
```

Read more about the `Find`/`Find` and `Restrict` methods in the articles that I wrote for the technical blog:

- [How To: Use Find and FindNext methods to retrieve Outlook mail items from a folder (C#, VB.NET)](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/09/20/outlook-find-findnext-retrieve-mail/)
- [How To: Use Restrict method to retrieve Outlook mail items from a folder](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/09/23/outlook-restrict-method-retrieve-mail/)

If you need to process multiple folders at once you may consider using the `AdvancedSearch` method. See [Advanced search in Outlook programmatically: C#, VB.NET](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2012/05/31/outlook-search-csharp-vbnet/) for more information.